# Aligning two systems

Tags: align

I am trying to create [image]

but when I do I get this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{align*}&\begin{matrix*}[l]%
x_8 = 93  &  y_8 = 64  &  z_8 = 61\\  
x_7 = 186  &  y_7 = 32 &  z_7 = 61\\
x_6 = 231  &  y_6 = 32  &  z_6 = 29\\
x_5 = 462 & y_5 = 16 & z_5 = 29\\
x_4 = 483 & y_4 = 16 & z_4 = 13\\
x_3 = 966 & y_3 = 8 & z_3 = 13\\
x_2 = 975 & y_2 = 8 & z_2 = 5\\
x_1 = 1950 & y_1 = 4 & z_1 = 5\\
x_0 = 1953 & y_0 = 4 & z_1 = 1
\end{matrix*}
\quad
&\begin{matrix*}[l]% 
x_5 = 65 & y_5 = 128 & z_5 = 1\\
x_4 = 130 & y_4 = 64 & z_4 = 1\\
x_3 = 260 & y_3 = 32 & z_3 = 1\\
x_2 = 520 & y_2 = 16 & z_2 = 1\\
x_1 = 1040 & y_1 = 8 & z_1 = 1\\
x_0 = 2080 & y_0 = 4 & z_0 = 1
\end{matrix*}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Off-topic: It's bad practice to use an `align*` environment to generate (de facto) a single unnumbered display-math structure. Use `\[ ... \]` instead.

Comment: does the index (subscript) ever have a value >9 ?  if so, how do you want the various pieces to be aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses two `array` environments. Observe that I've set the numbers to the right of each `=` symbol to be right-aligned; if you prefer left-alignment, just change

```
\begin{array}[t]{*{2}{r@{{}={}}r @{\quad}} r@{{}={}}r}
```

to

```
\begin{array}[t]{*{2}{r@{{}={}}l @{\quad}} r@{{}={}}l}
```

Or, if you prefer, use two `aligned` environments side-by-side, using `[t]` positioning specifiers. This approach entails making fewer modifications to the code you've posted in your query. However, it doesn't afford the option to right-align the numbers to the right of the `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[  % Solution 1: Use two side-by-side 'array' environments
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{array}[t]{*{2}{r@{{}={}}r @{\quad}} r@{{}={}}r}
x_8 &   93 & y_8 & 64 & z_8 & 61\\  
x_7 &  186 & y_7 & 32 & z_7 & 61\\
x_6 &  231 & y_6 & 32 & z_6 & 29\\
x_5 &  462 & y_5 & 16 & z_5 & 29\\
x_4 &  483 & y_4 & 16 & z_4 & 13\\
x_3 &  966 & y_3 &  8 & z_3 & 13\\
x_2 &  975 & y_2 &  8 & z_2 &  5\\
x_1 & 1950 & y_1 &  4 & z_1 &  5\\
x_0 & 1953 & y_0 &  4 & z_1 &  1
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}[t]{*{2}{r@{{}={}}r @{\quad}} r@{{}={}}r}
x_5 &   65 & y_5 & 128 & z_5 & 1\\
x_4 &  130 & y_4 &  64 & z_4 & 1\\
x_3 &  260 & y_3 &  32 & z_3 & 1\\
x_2 &  520 & y_2 &  16 & z_2 & 1\\
x_1 & 1040 & y_1 &   8 & z_1 & 1\\
x_0 & 2080 & y_0 &   4 & z_0 & 1
\end{array}
\]

\[ % Solution 2: Use two side-by-side 'aligned' environments
\begin{aligned}[t]
x_8 &= 93  &  y_8 &= 64  &  z_8 &= 61\\  
x_7 &= 186  &  y_7 &= 32 &  z_7 &= 61\\
x_6 &= 231  &  y_6 &= 32  &  z_6 &= 29\\
x_5 &= 462 & y_5 &= 16 & z_5 &= 29\\
x_4 &= 483 & y_4 &= 16 & z_4 &= 13\\
x_3 &= 966 & y_3 &= 8 & z_3 &= 13\\
x_2 &= 975 & y_2 &= 8 & z_2 &= 5\\
x_1 &= 1950 & y_1 &= 4 & z_1 &= 5\\
x_0 &= 1953 & y_0 &= 4 & z_1 &= 1
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
x_5 &= 65 & y_5 &= 128 & z_5 &= 1\\
x_4 &= 130 & y_4 &= 64 & z_4 &= 1\\
x_3 &= 260 & y_3 &= 32 & z_3 &= 1\\
x_2 &= 520 & y_2 &= 16 & z_2 &= 1\\
x_1 &= 1040 & y_1 &= 8 & z_1 &= 1\\
x_0 &= 2080 & y_0 &= 4 & z_0 &= 1
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{lll@{\hskip 3em}lll}%
x_8 = 93  &  y_8 = 64  &  z_8 = 61  & x_5 = 65 & y_5 = 128 & z_5 = 1 \\
x_7 = 186  &  y_7 = 32 &  z_7 = 61 & x_4 = 130 & y_4 = 64 & z_4 = 1  \\
x_6 = 231  &  y_6 = 32  &  z_6 = 29  & x_3 = 260 & y_3 = 32 & z_3 = 1 \\
x_5 = 462 & y_5 = 16 & z_5 = 29  & x_2 = 520 & y_2 = 16 & z_2 = 1 \\
x_4 = 483 & y_4 = 16 & z_4 = 13 &x_1 = 1040 & y_1 = 8 & z_1 = 1  \\
x_3 = 966 & y_3 = 8 & z_3 = 13  & x_0 = 2080 & y_0 = 4 & z_0 = 1\\
x_2 = 975 & y_2 = 8 & z_2 = 5 \\
x_1 = 1950 & y_1 = 4 & z_1 = 5 \\
x_0 = 1953 & y_0 = 4 & z_0 = 1
\end{array}\]%


\begin{alignat*}{6}
x_8  &=  93  &\hskip 1.2em  y_8 & = 64  &\hskip 1.2em    z_8  &=  61  &\hskip 3em x_5  &=  65 &\hskip 1.2em   y_5  &=  128 & \hskip 1.2em  d z_5  &=  1 \\
x_7  &=  186  &  y_7 &=  32 &  z_7  &=  61 & x_4  &=  130 & y_4  &=  64 & z_4  &=  1  \\
x_6  &=  231  &  y_6  &=  32  &  z_6  &=  29  &  x_3  &=  260 & y_3  &=  32 & z_3  &=  1  \\
x_5 &=   462 & y_5 &=   16 & z_5 &=   29  & x_2 &=   520 & y_2 &=   16 & z_2 &=   1 \\
x_4 &=   483 & y_4 &=   16 & z_4 &=   13 &x_1 &=   1040 & y_1 &=   8 & z_1 &=   1  \\
x_3 &=   966 & y_3 &=   8 & z_3 &=   13  & x_0 &=   2080 & y_0 &=   4 & z_0 &=   1\\
x_2 &=   975 & y_2 &=   8 & z_2 &=   5 \\
x_1 &=   1950 & y_1 &=   4 & z_1 &=   5 \\
x_0 &=   1953 & y_0 &=   4 & z_0 &=   1
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have top alignment starting from you code, you can either add emty rows to the smaller matrix, or change `matrix*` into `array` and use the `[t]` optional argument:

```
\begin{align*}
&\begin{matrix*}[l]%
x_8 = 93  &  y_8 = 64  &  z_8 = 61\\
x_7 = 186  &  y_7 = 32 &  z_7 = 61\\
x_6 = 231  &  y_6 = 32  &  z_6 = 29\\
x_5 = 462 & y_5 = 16 & z_5 = 29\\
x_4 = 483 & y_4 = 16 & z_4 = 13\\
x_3 = 966 & y_3 = 8 & z_3 = 13\\
x_2 = 975 & y_2 = 8 & z_2 = 5\\
x_1 = 1950 & y_1 = 4 & z_1 = 5\\
x_0 = 1953 & y_0 = 4 & z_1 = 1
\end{matrix*}
&\begin{matrix*}[l]%
x_5 = 65 & y_5 = 128 & z_5 = 1\\
x_4 = 130 & y_4 = 64 & z_4 = 1\\
x_3 = 260 & y_3 = 32 & z_3 = 1\\
x_2 = 520 & y_2 = 16 & z_2 = 1\\
x_1 = 1040 & y_1 = 8 & z_1 = 1\\
x_0 = 2080 & y_0 = 4 & z_0 = 1\\
\\
\\
\\
\end{matrix*}
\end{align*}\\

\[ %
\begin{array}[t]{lll}%
x_8 = 93  &  y_8 = 64  &  z_8 = 61\\
x_7 = 186  &  y_7 = 32 &  z_7 = 61\\
x_6 = 231  &  y_6 = 32  &  z_6 = 29\\
x_5 = 462 & y_5 = 16 & z_5 = 29\\
x_4 = 483 & y_4 = 16 & z_4 = 13\\
x_3 = 966 & y_3 = 8 & z_3 = 13\\
x_2 = 975 & y_2 = 8 & z_2 = 5\\
x_1 = 1950 & y_1 = 4 & z_1 = 5\\
x_0 = 1953 & y_0 = 4 & z_1 = 1
\end{array}
\qquad%
\begin{array}[t]{lll}
x_5 = 65 & y_5 = 128 & z_5 = 1\\
x_4 = 130 & y_4 = 64 & z_4 = 1\\
x_3 = 260 & y_3 = 32 & z_3 = 1\\
x_2 = 520 & y_2 = 16 & z_2 = 1\\
x_1 = 1040 & y_1 = 8 & z_1 = 1\\
x_0 = 2080 & y_0 = 4 & z_0 = 1
\end{array}
 \]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use alignat. Is there a way to do it by fixing my code?

Comment: I've added  two variants with slight modifications of your code.